# How to show minimum and maximum values of a column as x ticks at the center of the bins

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, histplot

I would like to display x-axis value on the center of each bin. Besides, minimum and maximum value of the column here *flipper_length_mm* should be shown first and lastly, respecively. Below you can find my attempt.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
penguins = penguins.dropna()

max_n = penguins.flipper_length_mm.max()
min_n = penguins.flipper_length_mm.min()
bins = 15
step = (max_n - min_n) / bins
print(min_n, max_n, bins, step)
# 172.0 231.0 15 3.933333333333333

arr_div = np.arange(min_n + step / 2, max_n + step / 2, step=step)
arr_div_r = np.round(arr_div, 0).astype(int)

sns.histplot(data=penguins, x="flipper_length_mm", hue="sex", bins=bins, multiple="stack")
plt.xticks(arr_div, arr_div_r)
# To see the real values without rounding
# plt.xticks(arr_div)

plt.show()
```

Using the code above, the centered x ticks or x axis values are not minimum or maximum of *flipper_length_mm* column. I would like to show minimum value as 172 and maximum  as 231. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use minor ticks to add 2 special tick positions at the start and end.  Making them larger avoids overlap with the existing (major) ticks and emphasizes they're differently spaced. Optionally, you can also change their color. As the x-axis label is moved by the largest ticks, setting its padding negative avoids superfluous white space.

(Note that `np.arange(start, stop, step)` can sometimes include the `stop` value, due to floating point precision issues. The code below uses a `stop` value at `max_n` to make sure the ticks stop earlier.)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
penguins = penguins.dropna()

max_n = penguins.flipper_length_mm.max()
min_n = penguins.flipper_length_mm.min()
bins = 15
step = (max_n - min_n) / bins

arr_div = np.arange(min_n + step / 2, max_n, step=step)
arr_div_r = np.round(arr_div, 0).astype(int)

ax = sns.histplot(data=penguins, x="flipper_length_mm", hue="sex", bins=bins, multiple="stack")
ax.set_xticks(arr_div, arr_div_r)
ax.set_xticks([min_n, max_n], [round(min_n), round(max_n)], minor=True)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='minor', length=14, color='b', labelcolor='b')
ax.xaxis.labelpad = -4
ax.margins(x=0)
sns.despine()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: using minor ticks to show start and end]

Comment: Thanks! Is there a trick so that x-axis starts at 0?

Comment: You can set `ax.xlim(xmin=0)` to let x start at zero. In this case, that would give a plot with a lot of empty space.  Note that, for more control, instead of `bins=15`, you can also give a list of bin edges.  E.g `bins=np.linspace(0, max_n, 16)`.